# Javascript and css in header vs including separate document?

Tags: javascript, css, header, page-load-time

Im just curious if there is any advantage to using (a minified version of) javascript and css in the header with the script and style tags **vs** including them from a separate document via link to css and a script to javascript?

Isn't there theoretically added page load time in the second way since there would be extra page requests?

so this:

```
<head>

    <script>
        //Javascript
    </script>
    <style>
        //Css
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    //Content Here
</body>

</html>
```

Vs This:

```
<head>

    <script src='http://someJavascript.com/link/to/file.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <link href='http://someCSS.com/link/to/file.css' rel='stylesheet'>

</head>

<body>
    //Content Here
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is more professional to have it externally loaded on to the page, however for a minimal CSS or JavaScript it is fine to have few lines of code directly in the page header. However your number one go to should be external file as it is a standard. Welcome to SO and best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage is mostly modularity. If you use the same JS or CSS in multiple files, it's best to keep them in one place. That way, if you make a change to them, you don't have to update all the files, you just update it in one place.

But if the JS or CSS is specific to a particular file, you might as well put them directly in the file rather than force a separate request.

Comment: Agree +1, sums it up quite well.

Comment: This is good... however i am using PHP so i can still keep the file in one place and include it on multiple pages...

Answer (score 0):

I would generally do the scripting or styling inline, although it is useful to load it remotely if you want something for multiple different HTML files (e.g. the same stylesheet for all the pages on a website). Load times increase a bit, but unless you are expecting to get thousands of page loads, it's pretty minimal. Your "header" tags should also be "head" tags.

Comment: Thanks i fixed that! lol I was just typing it up real quick...

As for the multiple pages i was just doing a require with PHP so it is one document on multiple pages...

Answer (score 0):

Having the JavaScript and CSS in separate files allows browsers and proxies to cache them - so if the main section of the page is dynamically generated, only the changing content will get re-downloaded on a reload.